# Moving bytes from one files to another

Tags: bash, files

I have an empty file (only zeroes are in it) of size 9,0KB and I need to write another file (with size 1,1KB) to it, but the first file must not lose it's. So if the whole file is 00000000000000... now, I need to write second file in it and leave the zeroes as they are. I have tried to use dd, but I haven't succeed - file resizes.

```
dd if=out/one.img of=out/go.img
```

Does anybody know how can I do it?

Comment: Silly question: how does append file behave? `cat file1 >> file_of_zeros`

Comment: An empty file is not 9KB: if you mean "9KB worth of zeroes", then it's not empty :). If you want to ADD the second file, obviously the filesize changes. If you want to overwrite last part, you need to acknowledge the file isn't "empty", but has zeroes you want to replace with whatever is in your file, and go from there.

Comment: phipsalabim: append (cat) appends...

Nanne: true, it's not empty, but it's full of zeroes. I want to overwrite beginning.

Comment: I think I understand what you want, let's reduce the scale. The first file (zeros) size is ten bits and its content is "0000000000". The second file size is 3 bits and its content is "101". You want this as the resultant file: "1010000000". Is that right? Write the second file at the begining of the first maintaining the rest of the first file data?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
dd if=out/one.img of=out/go.img conv=notrunc
```

See also [`man dd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd).